# Align the text of a particular listbox item in C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently working with a listbox in C# and I'll like to right-align some of the items as i add them. Please can anyone help?
Thanks

This is the code:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   lstMsg.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                lstMsg.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                lstMsg.Items.Add("You:" + txtMsg.Text);
        }
```

Comment: Sure we can help. Can you please help us and post some code so we can see where it is you are having the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask], before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 0):

Use RightToLeft property

```
    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
         lstMsg.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
         lstMsg.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
         lstMsg.Items.Add("You:" + txtMsg.Text);
         lstMsg.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes; //Check this
        //To align to left, use RightToLeft.No
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it right-aligns every item in the listbox. I want to right-align only the item I'm adding now, not the entire listbox.